# Calculate CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have VBA code that calculates the CRC16 CCITT value of a text string, and now I am planning to use it on a Google Sheet, but do not have any idea how to convert the VBA code to Google Apps Script.

```
Function crc_ccitt_ffff(strParam As String) As String
  Const CRC_POLY_CCITT       As Long = &H1021&
  Const CRC_START_CCITT_FFFF As Long = &HFFFF&

  Dim crc_tabccitt(0 To 255) As Long, crc As Long, b() As Byte, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long
                                                                          
                                                                         
  For i = 0 To 255
      crc = 0
      c = i * 256
      For j = 0 To 7
          If (crc Xor c) And 32768 Then
             crc = (crc * 2) Xor CRC_POLY_CCITT
          Else
             crc = crc * 2
          End If
          c = c * 2
          Next j
      crc_tabccitt(i) = crc
  Next i
                                                                          
  b = strParam
  crc = CRC_START_CCITT_FFFF
  For i = 0 To UBound(b) Step 2
      crc = (crc * 256) Xor crc_tabccitt(((crc \ 256) Xor b(i)) And 255)
      crc = ((crc \ 65536) * 65536) Xor crc
  Next i
  crc_ccitt_ffff = Hex(crc)
End Function
```

Test vector:

`00020101021129370016A000000677010111021312345678901215802TH5406500.5553037646304`

Expected result: `3D85`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It would help if you could show some test inputs and the expected results for those inputs so that an implementation can be tested.

Comment: hey @doubleunary, thanks for your advise, i,ve edited the question with detailed test input and the expected results.

Comment: It seems that you have re-posted exactly the same question at [Calculate CRC16 CCITT FALSE in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243628/calculate-crc16-ccitt-false-in-google-apps-script). That is not a recommended practice.

Comment: Ohh I'm so sorry about that, i'm just trying to edit the title so the question and title will be relatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the function below. This code gets the expected result for the test string you quote.

This custom function will work with a single text string argument, or a range of cells that contain text strings. It only calculates a checksum for text strings — empty cells and numeric cells are ignored.

```
/**
* Calculates a CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE checksum.
* 
* @param {A2:D42} text A range of text strings for which to calculate checksums.
* @param {true} hex_output Use true to get hexadecimal results, and false to get decimal results. Defaults to true.
* @return {String[][]} The hexadecimal or decimal checksums for text.
* @customfunction
*/
function crc_ccitt_ffff(text, hex_output = true) {
  // adapted from https://github.com/damonlear/CRC16-CCITT
  // by https://stackoverflow.com/users/13045193/doubleunary
  // for https://stackoverflow.com/q/68235740/13045193
  // 在线校验工具及相关说明：http://www.ip33.com/crc.html
  if (!Array.isArray(text))
    text = [[text]];
  const polynomial = 0x1021;
  return text.map(row => row.map(string => {
    if (!string.length)
      return null;
    const bytes = Array.from(String(string))
      .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff); // gives 8 bits; higher bits get discarded
    let crc = 0xffff;
    bytes.forEach(byte => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let bit = 1 === (byte >> (7 - i) & 1);
        let c15 = 1 === (crc >> 15 & 1);
        crc <<= 1;
        if (c15 ^ bit)
          crc ^= polynomial;
      }
    });
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return hex_output ? crc.toString(16).toUpperCase() : crc;
  }));
}
```

Comment: hey @doubleunary, mmm when i test it and compare with my vba code, the calculated value was different 

With input string : 00020101021129370016A000000677010111021312345678901215802TH5406500.5553037646304
The output : 3D85

But your code output : 5E28

Any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: I think I got it. Your VBA code does not implement `CRC-16/CCITT` but `CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE`. Adapted [damonlear/CRC16-CCITT](https://github.com/damonlear/CRC16-CCITT) and edited the answer.

Comment: Ohh yeah right, thanks for your correction and help. It works